# Cannot open large concatenated zip file with unzip, though it opened fine with Archive Utility, get a central directory error

Tags: zip

I have downloaded a 7Gb zip file full of pdfs and movies in four (4) parts from an ftp server.  I concatenate these four files into a single zip file on my machine and it unzip just fine with my Mac's Archive Utility.

However, when I upload these files to my Red Hat server, I am unable to unzip this concatenated zip file. I get this error:

```
Archive:  science_team_meeting_archive.zip
warning [science_team_meeting_archive.zip]:  2491989543 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
(attempting to process anyway)
error [science_team_meeting_archive.zip]:  start of central directory not found;
zipfile corrupt.
(please check that you have transferred or created the zipfile in the
appropriate BINARY mode and that you have compiled UnZip properly)
```

Ideas?

Comment: More answers: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/208139/how-to-deal-with-unzip-error-on-a-large-file-in-osx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
zip -F science_team_meeting_archive.zip -O science_team_meeting_archive.fixed.zip
```

If that doesn't work, you just need more 'F's

```
zip -FF science_team_meeting_archive.zip -O science_team_meeting_archive.fixed.zip
```

If either of these work, you then unzip normally with:

```
unzip science_team_meeting_archive.fixed.zip
```

For more info about this, use:

```
man zip
```

Answer (score 3):

### 7z x

I had the same issue with `unzip %x` on Linux for a `.zip` file larger than 4GB, compounded with a `only DEFLATED entries can have EXT descriptor` error.

The command `7z x` resolved all my issues though.

Be careful though, the command `7z x` will extract all files with a path rooted in the current directory. The option `-o` allows to specify an output directory.